# Перепривязать домен на хостинге timeweb

Tags: хостинг, домен

Сделана другая версия сайта и необходимо отлинковать домен от старого сайта и привязать к новому. Делаю всё как и полагается, привязываю домен к другому сайту но при переходе по ссылке попадаю всё равно на старый сайт. Привязка должна происходить мгновенно.
Слышал версию, что директория должна называться так же как и домен.
Подскажите, как в итоге поступить?

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы вносили изменения в настройки домена (NS или A-записи меняли), то нужно подождать пока изменения вступят в силу. Также нужно уточнить у хостера как организована файловая структура (скорее таки нужно,чтобы папка с сайтом называлась также как и домен). Ну и обратите внимание на особенности CMS на Вашем сайте. 
Есть некоторые CMS,которые в своей БД или в конфигурационном файле хранят предыдущее имя Вашего сайта (WordPress, OpenCart) и там соответственно нужно вносить правки. Ваш новый сайт ведь как-то назывался раньше, как-то же вы к нему обращались? Вот это имя и надо заменить на новое.